# How to send a placeholder calendar invite to another email address when a calendar invite is received in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

1) A calendar invite is received in email1@x.com
2) Create and send a new invite to email2@z.com for the same time range and priority.

This would show where I'm available on both emails.

Notes:

- I'm using the same outlook instance for both email addresses.
- I'm unable to create a rule to forward emails and it wouldn't give me the anonymized meeting invite I need anyway.

Using Outlook 365

Comment: If rules cannot be used, you will have to use VBA or add-in to achieve this. Outlook doesn't provide other options to automatically create a meeting.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured.